# How to check if items in "getPersistedUriPermissions" are the ones you need

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

When using `getPersistedUriPermissions()`, assuming it already contains some `UriPermission`s, how do you know if they are the correct permissions for what you are trying to do?

For example, if you get write permissions to an SD card (or an area of an SD Card), and the user swaps the SD Card to another one, those permissions are no longer valid. How can you check whether the permissions in the list returned from the function are either usable or not (thus requiring you to ask for permission again)?

Previously I was just checking if I had at least one permission, but that no longer works when they use multiple SD cards etc.. However I don't see a way to tell if the `UriPermission` in the list is the one I need. The example one is:

```
UriPermission {uri=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/abcdef, modeFlags=3, persistedTime=abcdef}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not heavily tested yet.  I'm still working through the intricacies (read: massive design holes) of the Document API.

```
/**
 * Returns the permissible root uri if one exists, null if not.
 *
 * @return The tree URI.
 */
public Uri getPermissibleRoot(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
        return null;

    for (UriPermission permission : mRootPermissions)
    {
        // TODO: This will not work with file schemes, there might not be a way to do so...
        String permissionTreeId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(permission.getUri());
        String uriTreeId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri);

        if (uriTreeId.startsWith(permissionTreeId))
        {
            return permission.getUri();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is part of an Android library I'm working on.  It's far from ready for prime-time, but I hope to make it easier to work with the Document API:

https://github.com/rcketscientist/DocumentActivity

Comment: I just stumbled across this too. The Uris returned from PersistedUriPermissions do not exactly match the ones sent in via TakePersistableUriPermission.

Comment: @joe indeed. That's precisely why Anthony's solution works - the Ids returned by `DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId` are nominal and can be properly compared for equality (or in his case, testing "parentality")

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getPersistedUriPermissions()` to check permissions like this:

```
private boolean checkStoragePermissions(){
        List<UriPermission> list = getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            if(list.get(i).getUri() == myUri && list.get(i).isWritePermission()){
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

as an example, where `myUri` can be a uri on the currently mounted SD card.

Note that `getUri()` returns the Uri but with `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/` appended, and will also conform to RFC 2396.

Example: I choose a folder called 'xyz' on my SD Card so getUri() would return something like this: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3142-4535%3Axyz

Comment: Shouldn't the comparison be `list.get(i).getUri().equals(myUri)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rewrite of checkStoragePermission

```
//how to call.
//1. save a granted perm as a string so you can pass it back in
// example: String alreadyHavePermsString="content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3337-6133%3ASEE";
//
//2.create a Uri by parsing and decoding
// example: Uri treeUri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(alreadyHavePermsString));
//
//3. return a bool so you know if the permission has been granted
// example boolean bcp = checkStoragePermissions(treeUri);
//
// now the function 
private boolean checkStoragePermissions(Uri myUri) //myUri already decoded. see "how to call" #1
{
    String sMyUri            = myUri.toString(); //%3A already decoded into a ':'
    List<UriPermission> list = getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions(); //get the list
    for (int i = 0; i        < list.size(); i++)
    {
        UriPermission p = list.get(i);    //dereference to isolate the permission and make readable
        String strP     = Uri.decode(p.getUri().toString()); //decode and stringify for the equals test
        if(strP.equals    (sMyUri))
        {
            Log.d("checkstorage","found "+sMyUri); //show status
            if(p.isWritePermission()) //now i can reuse the dereferenced permission p
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```